# Lifting a boolean statement to a proposition

Tags: agda, standard-library

Given a list, a "property" (a function to `Bool`s), and a proof `any f xs ≡ true`, I want to get a value of `Any (λ x → T (f x)) ns`, i.e. I want a to convert a proof from `any` to a proof of `Any`.

So far, I have been able to sketch the proof, but I am stuck at a seemingly simple statement (please see the second to last line below):

```
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Bool.Properties
open import Data.List
open import Data.List.Relation.Unary.Any using (Any; here; there)
open import Data.Unit
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality 

≡→T : ∀ {b : Bool} → b ≡ true → T b
≡→T refl = tt

any-val : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} (f) (ns : List A)
        → any f ns ≡ true
        → Any (λ x → T (f x)) ns
any-val f [] ()
any-val f (n ∷ ns) any-f-⟨n∷ns⟩≡true with f n
...                            | true  = here (≡→T ?)
...                            | false = there (any-val f ns any-f-⟨n∷ns⟩≡true)
```

Apparently, I need to prove that `f n ≡ true`, which should be trivial to prove because we are in the `true` branch of the `with` statement `f ≡ true`.

What is supposed to go in there? What am I understanding incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the `inspect` idiom, which I already described thoroughly in another answer here:

[`with f x` matches `false`, but cannot construct `f x == false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718174/with-f-x-matches-false-but-cannot-construct-f-x-false/58720704#58720704)

This gives the following code, which I cleaned up, including imports:

```
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.List
open import Data.List.Relation.Unary.Any using (Any; here; there)
open import Data.Unit
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality 
open import Function

≡→T : ∀ {b : Bool} → b ≡ true → T b
≡→T refl = tt

any-val : ∀ {a} {A : Set a}
  f (ns : List A) → any f ns ≡ true → Any (T ∘ f) ns
any-val f (x ∷ l) p with f x | inspect f x
... | false | _ = there (any-val f l p)
... | true | [ fx≡true ] = here (≡→T fx≡true)
```

On a side note, be sure that you have Agda updated to the last version so that you don't have to handle the empty case `any-val f [] ()`, as in your code.

Comment: Just figured it out too (I was reading the documentation. Damn, I should look a the documentation before posting, but there are so many things to look at in the documentation!). Anyway. Thanks a lot! I had no idea there was no need to handle the empty case. I just added because I felt obliged to do it

Comment: No worries, it can be sometimes hard to find the required information, especially in the Agda std lib. About the empty case, it's quite a new behavior, which is more of a syntactic sugar, but still very convenient. Glad I could help.