# Agda equivalent of `destruct <term> eqn:<identifier>`

Tags: coq, agda

I understand that Agda does case analysis using with-clauses, which is similar Coq's destruct tactic. The destruct tactic has a [variant](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.destruct-eqn) of the form `destruct <term> eqn:<identifier>`, which additionally adds to the context an equation between `<term>` and the value that `<term>` takes in each case. Is there an analogous way to add this equation to context in Agda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `inspect` idiom which will do exactly what you require.

I have described thoroughly how to use it in the following answer:

[`with f x` matches `false`, but cannot construct `f x == false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718174/with-f-x-matches-false-but-cannot-construct-f-x-false/58720704#58720704)